# Eclipse Build Refreshing Hang

Tags: eclipse, build, refresh, freeze

This behavior just started two days ago.  When I save a file, automatic build kicks in.  (I don't want to turn off automatic builds.)  Eclipse blocks the UI during a build.  It says "Refreshing".

I took call stacks of Eclipse when hung and when okay.  I found this thread.  What can I do to fix the hang?

Here's what I tried:

- Manually refreshing the project hangs
- Checked Error view and found nothing
- Checked .metadata/.log and found nothing
- Delete .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.project
- Run Eclipse with -clean option
- Run Eclipse with -clean and -clearPersistedState options
- Increase heap size

I noticed that saving a file does not trigger the UI blocking hang, but the build does take a while.  Making a change and saving the file again while the build is going causes the UI to block.

```
"Worker-49: Building" #498 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=9125.00ms elapsed=662.08s tid=0x0000017e2de80070 nid=0x6c80 runnable  [0x0000003ca1cfd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileNatives.internalGetFileInfoW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileNatives.fetchFileInfo(LocalFileNatives.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileHandler.fetchFileInfo(LocalFileHandler.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFileNativesManager.fetchFileInfo(LocalFileNativesManager.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.fetchInfo(LocalFile.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.fetchInfo(FileStore.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.childInfos(FileStore.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.getLocalList(UnifiedTree.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.addChildren(UnifiedTree.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.addNodeChildrenToQueue(UnifiedTree.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.accept(UnifiedTree.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refreshResource(FileSystemResourceManager.java:978)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refresh(FileSystemResourceManager.java:961)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1573)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.refreshResources(MavenBuilderImpl.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$$Lambda$1256/0x0000000801a3aa90.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$$Lambda$1254/0x0000000801a3a388.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

@howlger suggested that I open the Maven Workspace Build view in Eclipse.  Here is what it shows.

[image: Maven WorkSpace Build view]

**Configuration**

- Eclipse: 2023-03 (4.27.0 - build 20230309-1520)
- Windows: 11 version 22H2 build 22621.1555

Comment: You might use the _Maven Workspace Build_ view to track down the issue, assuming it is caused by build cycles of Maven projects (the stack trace shows that `m2e` is involved).

Comment: Is your workspace on your fastest, local, disk?

Comment: @nitind Yes.  My workspace is on the internal SSD disk... the only internal disk.

Comment: @howlger I added the Maven Workspace Build view.  The delta makes sense.  The resources makes sense.  I doubt either of these would be much trouble for Maven.

Comment: The screenshot was taken after after the _Maven Workspace Build_ view has been opened and then the issue has been reproduced, right? If yes, it seems not caused by Maven build cycles. UI freezes can be tracked down with the _UI Freeze Monitor_ which can be enabled in the preferences _General > UI Freeze Monitor_.

Comment: @howlger Correct.  The screenshot was taken after the issue was reproduced.  I enabled UI Freeze Monitoring.  Where do I find the output?  I don't see anything in the Error Log view nor the ./metadata/.log.  The UI doesn't freeze per se.  The "User Operation is Waiting" dialog box opens.  I call this a freeze even though the UI remains responsive since I can't get anything done.

Comment: The _UI Freeze Monitor_ is only for real UI freezes. You might [enable tracing in Eclipse](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePerformance/article.html#using-the-build-in-tracing-facilities-of-eclipse), especially `org.eclipse.core.resources/build/needbuild=true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse will do a refresh operation as part of a build.  If the project directory has a deep large tree of directories, then this will take a while.  Reducing the size of the tree of directories resolves this.